# Host alias for ssh

Tags: ssh, openssh

There are a few SSH destinations I will frequently be connecting to and I'm wondering if rather than remember the IP address I can create a host alias for them.  I'd like to be able to use...

`ssh -p xx user@domain.ssh`

I've tried establishing this host in `/etc/hosts` and unless there's a service I needed to restart it had no effect.

Comment: This should work fine. Paste the the entry in /etc/hosts file. Can you actually ping the host using the alias (if firewall is not block icmp)?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Sometimes it is more convenient to have configuration files in our home directory. This avoids having to be root to edit files, and also they can be configured in a way that other users have no access to this data. In addition this configuration will be backed up with our home and also will "survive" an OS upgrade.

To do so we can make a ssh configuration file `nano ~/.ssh/config` where we can put in valuable information for a connection. A simple entry may have the following content:

```
Host myremote             # any name for the host
HostName 192.168.178.05   # IP, .local, or hostname if defined
User username             # your username
Port 22                   # port to listen
```

There are many other options including user and authentication you can give here (see [manpage for ssh_config](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ssh_config))

We then can simply issue the following to connect to 192.168.178.05 on port 22:

```
ssh myremote
```

Comment: Note that you can also assign more than one host identifier, e.g. `Host myremote 192.168.178.05`. That way your settings will be used when you connect using the actual host name as well.

Comment: Don't forget to add parameter 'User' (if there is need) into your config file!

Comment: After ssh command '.ssh/config line 2: garbage at end of line; "#".' means do not include hashtags to your config file.

Comment: @Takkat How do we store alias for multiple servers?

Comment: @Anish Just add another `Host...`section separated by an empty line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ruby gem called [`sshez`](https://rubygems.org/gems/sshez). It interfaces your config file and makes adding ssh aliases easier.

**Install gem**

```
gem install sshez
```

**Add an alias `my_alias` for example**

```
sshez add my_alias root@example.com -p 1022
```

**Remove `my_alias` from your config file**

```
sshez remove my_alias
```

**List aliases**

```
sshez list
```

Now you can connect to `ssh my_alias` without worrying about editing your config file yourself.

Comment: latest docs http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/sshez/1.0.2

Answer (score 0):

The SSH config file is extremely useful but requires manually editing a file.
I use this Python package to automatically save the connection information at the time the ssh connection is made.
https://github.com/emileindik/slosh

Similar to the `sshez` tool also posted:

```bash
$ pip install slosh
$ slosh ubuntu@1.1.1.1 --save-as myserver
```

This will perform the desired ssh connection and also create the corresponding entry in your SSH config file.

[disclaimer] I created slosh