# how to give user server name instead of ip when connecting through SSH?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ssh

I have a virtualbox on which I have installed ubuntu 12.04. My host computer is Mac OS (mavericks). I did a SSH key copy to my remote (which is ubuntu server and I call it myubuntu).

when I did

```
ssh username@myubuntu
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ubuntuhadoop: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

but when I tried:

```
ssh username@66.90.115.178
```

I was able to log in to the remote server (which is myubuntu).

why is it need that I give IP address it connects properply but not the servername.

I am not sure if this is possible. But I found in one of youtube tutorials. 
`ssh myubuntu` (NOT username@myubuntu)
and logged onto the remote server, without username. is this possible?

Comment: This may give you the solution from the last part of your question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/257472/host-alias-for-ssh

Comment: check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45927052/249697

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have a few options.

If you need access from only a few locations, or a single location, update /etc/hosts

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

Add an entry for your server

```
66.90.115.178 myubuntu
```

Second, purchase or find a free DNS service, http://www.noip.com/free/ or similar.

Third, ssh uses your current user name by default, so if you have the same user name on both client and server, just ssh server_name

```
ssh your_server
```

You only need to specify a user name if the names are different or you want a new user

```
ssh new_user@your_server
```

Comment: I followed the first option since it is simple now. do I have to restart the computer. right now, it is hanging when I tried `ssh myubuntu` and I `get operation timed out`

Comment: Not sure about the hang, look at the output of `ssh -vvv myubuntu`

Comment: sorry, I had a typo on IP which I found out using `ssh -vvv`. after I fixed it works great!. one question though, why do you say `if you need access from only a few locations or a single location update /etc/hosts`. if you could give a line or two for the two methods you described and when they will be useful, they will be helpful for beginner like me. Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: Well, it is proportional to how many machines you need to edit /etc/hosts on vs the time it takes to configure a DNS server.

Comment: There's also an another option for local networks: Avahi (which is installed by default on Ubuntu Desktops).

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini - I've not had much success with Avahi and I do not think it will work over the internet, not sure ...

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: that's why I've written "for local networks" ;)

Comment: I am looking for this answer from last 2 days. thanks buddy 

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. I had defined another host as below (in /etc/hosts):

```
hostname1 IP1
hostname2 IP2
```

I changed it to:

```
IP1 hostname1
IP2 hostname2
```